# MySQL insert with autoincrement - is insert ignore neccessary to avoid concurrency issue?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, insert

I am using the simple INSERT statement in MySQL with innodb, with auto-increment in the primary id. Do I need to worry about if user A and user B execute the same script at the same moment, user A's insertion would be overwritten by user B's?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not. You can treat it as thread safe.

From reference:

> When accessing the auto-increment counter, InnoDB uses a special table-level AUTO-INC lock that it keeps to the end of the current SQL statement, not to the end of the transaction

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html